# Visio 2010 Shapes window is gone from the left panel. How do I get it back?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have lost my shapes window at the left side of my screen. I can't get it back. How do I open the shapes window?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Main ribbon > Show section > Task Panes > Shapes

or

View > Taskpanes > Shapes

Comment: Thank you. I have View> Taskpanes > Shapes. Oddly I don't have > Show section. Is this on the home tab?

Comment: View > Taskpanes does not have "shapes" as an option when you are inside a group. I cannot see "Show Section" inside or outside of a group.